# Linearity of Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform

[image]

Given the CTFT pair above, I am trying to find a Fourier transform of

[image]

I thought I could multiply both sides(time domain and frequency domain) by [image] to get the CTFT pair in the following form:

[image]

But that does not give me the correct result.

Could you please explain why? I thought it would've been okay to do so since [image] is nothing but a constant..

Edit:

[image]
[image]

This result is different from

[image]

Comment: I figured out. I forgot to multiply 5.

Comment: That's right, I guess you can delete your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP found the answer himself, and the question won't help anyone else (it was based on a trivial mistake).